# Multiple jQuery toggles not changing correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 toggle buttons, like this:

```js
 $(".ui.toggle" ).on( "click", function() {

      if (!$('#thetoggle').is(':checked')) {
        $('#thetoggle').prop('checked', true );
      }
      else {
        $('#thetoggle').prop('checked', false);
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui toggle checkbox">
      <input id="thetoggle" value="false" name="ownplace" type="checkbox">
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
      <input id="thetoggle" value="false" name="otherplace" type="checkbox">
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
    </div>
```

So when i click the second toggle, the first one changes the checked status, which it shouldn't do - I want them to change independently. I get why it isn't working, as I dont have any selectors for the second as this is the same as the first. However, I was wondering if there is a way to do this using some sort of easy selector which will work on all toggles in the future, with the ID of `thetoggle`

Comment: IDs have to be unique. `$('#thetoggle')` will just select the first one.

Comment: Why don't you just use `$(this)` to operate on the toggle that the user clicked on.

Comment: First, don't re-use ID use classes. Inside the click event you can do `$(this)` which references the clicked element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An id can only refer to **one** element, `$('#thetoggle')` will always return the first element with that id found in the DOM. You should use `class` instead, and in your event handler you can use:

```
$(this).find('.thetoggle`);
```

to get the child node. You could also remove class and id and just use tag type:

```
var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are able to be checked independanty without any javascript:

```html
<div class="ui toggle checkbox">
      <input class="thetoggle" value="false" name="ownplace" type="checkbox">
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
    </div>
    <div class="ui toggle checkbox">
      <input class="thetoggle" value="false" name="otherplace" type="checkbox">
      <label>&nbsp;</label>
    </div>
```

Although if you are looking for them to behave like radio buttons (i.e. only one can be checked at a time), you can try this (which does change the id's to classes):

```js
$(".thetoggle").change(function() {
  $(".thetoggle").prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ui toggle checkbox">
  <input class="thetoggle" value="false" name="ownplace" type="checkbox">
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
</div>
<div class="ui toggle checkbox">
  <input class="thetoggle" value="false" name="otherplace" type="checkbox">
  <label>&nbsp;</label>
</div>
```